# Not saving a text file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a txt file added to my project, which contains names of families. On a winform, the user have the ability to add new families to the list. I thought it worked, because after adding a new family, I made sure to refresh the combobox which displays all the families. However, after closing the program, the text file didn't save the newly added family, as a new line, so when reopening the program, the new family, added by the user don't show up.

I have added the text file as an Existing file, then set the Build Action to Embedded Resource, and the Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always.

Here's the line of code that would add the new line to the file.

```
File.AppendAllText(@"families.txt", Environment.NewLine + familyCorrectlyCoded);
```

... where familyCorrectlyCoded is the family name string.

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to Ian and WraithNath, I excluded the file from the project, and modified the File.AppendAllText line to this:

```
File.AppendAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\families.txt", Environment.NewLine + familyCorrectlyCoded);
```

Thanks again, lesson learned.

Comment: Don't make the text file part of the VS project.  When you run the program it modifies the copy that lives in the output directory.  But every time you build, it is copying the original file (from Resources) to the output directory, and overwriting any changes that may have been made.

Comment: To expand on Ians comment that I was just typing, change your code to copy the text file from resources if it does not exist already on the file system. this way it will default from the first run, then any changes made can be loaded from disk rather than resources.